# How to draw line on the UIImageView not for UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

How to draw a line on the UIImageView? I am using the UIImageView Sub Class, Its not support `drawRect:` method. I want to draw a line on the image view. How can I do this? Please help me. I am using below code for draw line.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat red[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(c, red);
    CGContextBeginPath(c);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(c, 5.0f, 5.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(c, 50.0f, 50.0f);
    CGContextStrokePath(c);
}
```

Comment: why are you drawing on the image View ? You can also draw line on UIImage !!!

Comment: I want to crop the image so user can click the image the draw the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code works by creating a new image the same size as the original, drawing a copy of the original image onto the new image, then drawing a 1 pixel line along to the top of the new image.

```
// UIImage *originalImage = <the image you want to add a line to>
// UIColor *lineColor = <the color of the line>

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(originalImage.size);

// Pass 1: Draw the original image as the background
[originalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];

// Pass 2: Draw the line on top of original image
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, originalImage.size.width, 0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [lineColor CGColor]);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

// Create new image
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

// Tidy up
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I wouldn't use a `UIImageView`.  In fact the docs say...

> If your subclass needs custom drawing code, it is recommended you use
>   UIView as the base class.

Use a `UIView`.

In the `UIView` add a `UIImageView` subView and put the image in there.  Now you can do you custom drawing in the `drawRect` method of the `UIView` and it will appear on top of the image.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);

    CGContextStrokeRect(context, self.bounds);
}
```

If this isn't working then the drawRect method probably isn't being called.  Set a breakpoint to test it.

Comment: Its 100% perfect way but I am already try like this. But the line not showing. So that only I will move to another solution. Please help me.

Comment: If the line isn't showing then I'd suggest debugging the drawing code.  Make sure it is actually being run and that it is showing something.  (Maybe try without the UIImageView first).  Edited to show some draw code that I know works...

Comment: I am using UIView class and then add the sub view of UIImageView. Finally using drawRect method to draw the image...! But Line is not showing. May be image will hide the line..? Please guide me.

Comment: You shouldn't be using drawRect to draw the image. Just let the UIImageView do its work. Try removing the UIImageView. If that works then you'll be best adding a UIView over the UIImageView and drawing into that.  I'd create a whole new custom view that has a UIImageView and a UIView subView.  The second UIView is then a subclass that managed to the custom drawing.  i.e. UIView subclass - subViews (UIImageView with UIIMage in it, UIView with a drawRect that manages the custom drawing).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about it in my opinion would be to take a invisible UIView of the same size as UIImageView for drawing and implement the touch methods on the UIView for drawing.

you can use something like:

```
CGPoint temp=[touch locationInView:self];
```

Use this in methods like:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Store all the points in an array and then draw those points on the UIImageView as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Muhammad Saad Ansari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17564782/4263646)

With Swift

```
func drawLines ( originalImage:UIImage, lineColor:CGColor ) -> UIImage{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImage.size,false,0.0)

originalImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake( 0, 0, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height ))

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, originalImage.size.width, 0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,lineColor);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

// Create new image
var newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

// Tidy up
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage
```

}