# draw line through two images

Tags: ios

please help.I have two image views - one black and one red . I draw a line through both , and after removing dark image view, the dark green line should remain on a red (cropped) and save to final image.

[image]

Comment: Can you put some code or more informations about what you are using ? Are you using UIViews, UIImages ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008419/how-to-draw-line-on-the-uiimageview-not-for-uiview

Comment: thanks. This is example how draw line on one image, but i need to on two or fix problem bellow. Red image view has a picture in the middle with clear color around (UIImage has 300x500, image has 150x200 and scaletofit). When I draw a line, so the line is on clear background too and it looks awful. I need to paint only to the part where something is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Explain what you have tried - with the code included in the question - and the problem encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have used three image view.

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *lineView;
IBOutlet UIImageView *blackView;
IBOutlet UIImageView *redView;
```

You need use the following code to get exact crop image as per the frame of `redView`.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(redView.frame.size);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGRect frame = lineView.frame;
frame.origin.x = lineView.frame.origin.x - redView.frame.origin.x ;
frame.origin.y = lineView.frame.origin.y - redView.frame.origin.y;

[redView.image drawInRect:redView.bounds];
[lineView.image drawInRect:frame];

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
redView.image = img;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```